KivyMD - No Button added
I'm trying to make a simple hangman game for my niece (and practice a little kivymd). I type the typical starting code, but nothing is added to the screen. The .py file is:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class AhorcadoScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass


class JuegodePalabrasApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("juegodepalabras.kv")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    JuegodePalabrasApp().run()

and I've tried 3 different kivy files. The first one is:
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"

    
    MDScrollView:
        md_bg_color: "white"

        MDButton:
            style: "elevated"

The second is:
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"
    

    MDScreen:
        MDScrollView:
            md_bg_color: "white"

            MDButton:
                style: "elevated"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                MDButtonText:
                    text: "Ahorcado"

And the last one:
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    AhorcadoScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainscreen"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        md_bg_color: "white"

        MDScreen:
            MDScrollView:
                md_bg_color: "white"

                MDButton:
                    style: "elevated"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "Ahorcado"

but in all cases, all I get is a white screen. I've done the same thing (changing the classes' names, of course) with another program and there was no problem.
I am using the same venv as the other program, not sure if that might be a problem.
Any ideas why this is happening?

You can solve it with adding the root widget (main widget of the app) which will later allow the app to show the other screens, some minor changes, adding all in one file (you can separate them), the result:

The complete code:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen



the_game="""
Screen:
    ScreenManager:
        id: mainx
        Screen:
            name: "home"

            BoxLayout:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (1,1,1, .9)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                orientation: "vertical"
                size: root.width, root.height
                

                BoxLayout:
                    id: m5
                    spacing: dp(10)
                    padding: dp(20)
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .55, "center_y": .4}
                    orientation: "vertical"

                    BoxLayout:
                        id: s_res2
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                        orientation: "vertical"
                    ScrollView:
                        id: maaa
                        do_scroll_x: False
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        pos_hint:{'center_x': .5,'center_y': .39}
                        size_hint_y: 10
                        BoxLayout:
                            canvas.before:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0,0,1,.2] # if white [1,1,1,1]
                                RoundedRectangle:
                                    radius: [30,]
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                            id: rvvv2
                            orientation: "vertical"
                            key_size: 'height'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size_hint_x: 0.9
                            height: self.minimum_height+45
                            padding: dp(20)
                            spacing: dp(8)
                            adaptive_height: True
                            BoxLayout:
                                MDIconButton:
                                    style: "elevated"
                                    icon: "home"
                                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                                MDLabel:
                                    style: "H5"
                                    text: "Ahorcado"
                                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                            BoxLayout:
                                MDIconButton:
                                    style: "elevated"
                                    icon: "battery"
                                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

                                MDLabel:
                                    style: "H5"
                                    text: "Snake Game"
                                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            FloatLayout:
                MDIconButton:
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: [1,0,0,.2] # if white [1,1,1,1]
                        RoundedRectangle:
                            radius: [30,]
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    icon: "plus"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
                    on_release: app.root.ids.mainx.current="ahorcado"

        Screen:
            name: "ahorcado"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [0,1,0,.2] # if white [1,1,1,1]
                RoundedRectangle:
                    radius: [30,]
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            MDCard:
            FloatLayout:
                MDIconButton:
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: [1,0,0,.2] # if white [1,1,1,1]
                        RoundedRectangle:
                            radius: [30,]
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    icon: "plus"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
                    on_release: app.root.ids.mainx.current="home"


"""

class JuegodePalabrasApp(MDApp):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self):
        global app
        app=MDApp.get_running_app()
        return Builder.load_string(the_game)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    JuegodePalabrasApp().run()

